# How may i move windows 10 to a folder and boot it from there?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub2

What's needed to enable multiboot of more than one windows 10 install without needing any additional partitions?  i imagine it might be possible by booting into something else and moving a list of folders and files comprising the current windows 10 install into a folder, and moving another windows 10 install out of another folder.  And presumably/hopefully nothing worse than more of the same in the other partitions windows 10 uses.  Clue me if there's more to it i'm not considering.  Anyway i would bet there's an even easier approach.  For example in linux this works great:  see my (gregrwm) answer to [Boot Linux system from a subdirectory on a partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/boot-linux-system-from-a-subdirectory-on-a-partition/441385#441385)  Grub2 is already the first stage of booting windows 10 for me, so that may help.  if needed it would be ok for the solution to employ additional tiny partitions, as long as the main large partition may somehow be shared.

Comment: What you describe is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Neat script at the [provided link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/boot-linux-system-from-a-subdirectory-on-a-partition/441385#441385), left an upvote.

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to change the root of a NTFS File System (which works differently then the INodes from Ext).

For my setup, i decided exactly this:

> if needed it would be ok for the solution to employ additional tiny partitions, as long as the main large partition may somehow be shared.

In order to share the Windows partition, you actually have to do not much. If it isn't already mounted automatically, just use the builtin diskmgmt tool to [assign the respective disk a drive letter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter).

There are also tools to mount EXT under Windows, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/124799/830570) or [alternatives here](https://www.troublefixers.com/4-ways-to-open-linux-or-ubuntu-ext-drive-partitions-in-windows/). I recall to have used [Paragon ExtFS for Windows free](https://download.cnet.com/Paragon-ExtFS-for-Windows/3000-2094_4-75956677.html) for a longer period.

---

Possible useful Information: It could make a difference if your disc is configured as BIOS/MBR or UEFI/GPT. For the first case, the (old) Master Boot Record contains from where to boot, for the second there is an EFI partition, that contains a small bootloader.

Windows also delivers its own bootloader, which provides comparable functionality as grub. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader) or [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries).

Hope this at least partly helps you.